# Интеграция jquery-ui-touch-punch в Laravel + Vue 2

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, vue.js

Привет, есть веб-приложение в котором много функционала базируется на растягивании элементов (resizable), но на мобильных устройствах хендлеры растягивания не чувствительны к тому что бы зацепить их пальцем. Поэтому пытаюсь подключить jquery-ui-touch-punch. И пока не могу разобраться как это сделать в ES6 синтаксисе.

Вот как я пробую:

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "nestedSortable": "^1.3.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
    "vue-drag-resize-rotate": "^2.0.8",
    "vue-resize": "^0.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.8.3-rc0",
    "vuex": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui');
require('jquery-ui-touch-punch');
```

Пробовал поменять местами `jquery-ui` и `jquery-ui-touch-punch` но так получается ошибка Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined

Подскажите, как правильно подключить jquery-ui-touch-punch в моем случае? 

Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте полный путь задать до файлов js или тогда нужно alias создавать в файле webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю разницы нет какой плагин, попробуйте замените мой плагин на ваш

На прямую указать путь:

```
require('../node_modules/jquery.maskedinput/src/jquery.maske‌​dinput');
```

Вот еще мой пример, через alias у меня не подключался inputmask
webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

function _path(p) {
    return path.join(__dirname, p);
}

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // jquery is NOT a peer dependency in jquery.inputmask so a alias
            // is used here to force jquery.inputmask to use your jquery
            // version
            'inputmask.dependencyLib': _path('node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery'),
            // Core library (order of these aliases shouldn't matter FYI)
            'inputmask' : _path('node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask'),
            // Allows use of jquery input mask via jquery chaining api/$('selector').inputmask(...)
            'jquery.inputmask': _path('node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask'),
            // Add extensions following the pattern below remember to import them as necessary in your .js files
            'inputmask.phone.extensions': _path('node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions'),
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: спасибо, плагин подключается, без Vue все хорошо работает но когда использую ui-resizable внутри Vue компонента, то плагин touch-punch не работает.

Comment: потому что события не обрабатываются наверное, вам или в директиву все обернуть надо или при mounted() вновь на события подписываться

Comment: @Ernest Faizullin  попробуйте в mounted() инициализировать плагин